# How often can COSMOS missions be repeated?

Tags: eve-online

How often can the COSMOS missions for high faction standings be repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly they cannot - it [has been requested](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=52368) to allow them to be repeatable once every six months/one year but I can't find any communication from CCP that states they've implemented this as a change.

Unlike the epic arc missions, once you've done a set of COSMOS missions you will not be able to repeat them. This is [further clarified on the EVE wiki](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/COSMOS_constellation):

> Most of these missions can only be completed once during your character's lifetime.

and...

> Warning: DO NOT FAIL, QUIT, DECLINE OR LET MISSION OFFER EXPIRE. It could lock you out from accessing other Cosmos agents.

Comment: I completed the SOE Arnon missions in August 2010 and then again in June 2012.  So they either were manually reset by CCP at some point or they are repeatable after some period of time.

Comment: SOE != COSMOS. SOE is an epic story arc, which is covered in the line `Unlike the epic arc missions`...